# Why is the copy constructor used here?

Tags: c++, constructor

I have the following code snippet:

```
template <class Callback>
void CreateRouteIteratorAndStore(ChordID searchValue,
                                 const Fingertable &initialTable,
                                 Client &client,
                                 Callback &&callback) {
    RouteIteratorSpecialization<RouteIteratorType::Online_StoreLookup>
        implementation{client, initialTable};
    new RouteIterator<Callback, decltype(implementation)>(
        std::move(implementation), std::move(searchValue), initialTable, client,
        std::forward<Callback>(callback));
}
```

The constructor of RouteIterator looks like this:

```
template <class Callback, class Impl>
RouteIterator<Callback, Impl>::RouteIterator(Impl impl,
                                             ChordID searchValue,
                                             const Fingertable &initialTable,
                                             Client &client,
                                             Callback &&callback)
    : impl_(std::move(impl)), ... {}
```

I get the error:

> Call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of
>   'nisan::RouteIteratorSpecialization'

At the call site of the RouteIterator constructor. RouteIteratorSpecialization has a move constructor but no copy constructor. This is expected But what I don't get is why the copy an not the move constructor is called.

Please don't care for the new. This objects life time is a mess which I need to fix at some point.

Edit:
The move constructor of `RouteIteratorSpecialization<RouteIteratorType::Online_StoreLookup>` is **not** noexcept. But that should not make a difference here. I just say it because it is a common error when trying to store move only objects in standard containers.

Comment: The only thing that I can think of would be to have `Impl &&impl` in the `RouteIterator` ctor. But that should not make a difference, should it?

Comment: If I do that the error is deferred to the initialisation inside the ctor: impl_(std::move(impl)). I don't want to do that because that prevents passing a const ref to a copyable spezialisation. The error stays the same. It calls the copy constructor.

Comment: What i can think about - in CTOr, you pass the IMpl by value (Impl impl), this may cause std::move to move an object, and the create it copy ? What if you change to pass an object by reference ?

Comment: Like I said in the previous comment: It does not make a difference. The error just surfaces whenever the move should occur.